# Excel COUNTIFS value not in a list

Tags: excel, formula, countif

I'm trying to count rows when values of a column are equal to a specific value AND, at the same time, a value of an another column is not in a list.

For example imagine the following table :

```
A  B       C
ID COUNTRY COLOR
1  GER     blue
2  GER     green
3  FRA     blue
4  USA     red 
5  GER     red
6  FRA     blue
7  GER     green
8  FRA     red
9  GER     gold
```

I Would like to count each rows where:

- COUNTRY = GER
- COLOR is not equal to red or blue

I tried the following formula:

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS(B:B;"GER;C:C{"<>red";"<>blue"}))
```

I was expecting 3 because I would like to count rows where the country is "GER" and color is everything except red and blue (Line 2, 7 and 9).

BUT output is 8.
This is surely because Excel detects 4 lines where the country is GER and color not **red** (1,2,7,9) + 4 lines GER and color not **blue** (2,5,7,9).

I know it is not complicated, but I can't figure it out.
Maybe one of you could give me a hint on how deals with my problem? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Shouldn't the result be three? Lines 2, 7 and 9?

Comment: when you use `{"<>red";"<>blue"})` actually this is like an OR operator. You are counting cells not equal to red OR blue. It does not work as an AND

Comment: Well, i don't understand in the case you mention it works as a "OR" but in the following one as a "AND" (C:C;"blue";C:C;"gold") Which is zero because our value can't have the two status blue and gold at the same time

Comment: in case `(C:C;"blue";C:C;"gold") ` it works as an AND because you selected twice same range and 2 conditions. Case `C:C;{"<>red";"<>blue"})` works as OR because you selected once a single arange, but applied 2 conditions. Depending on how you type it, it will work as AND or OR

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not sure why you combine `SUM` and `COUNTIFS`. A simple `COUNTIFS` formula with 3 criteria should be enough. You can use this formula:

```
=COUNTIFS(B2:B10;"GER";C2:C10;"<>red";C2:C10;"<>blue")
```

The result is 3 (GER-green, GER-green and GER-gold).

[image: COUNTIFS in Excel]

Comment: Thank you for that answer, it works well for me. In the case i would like to obtain the number of rows with COUNTRY = GER and COLOR = blue OR COLOR = red AND COLOR != gold : I tried =NB.SI.ENS(B:B;"GER";C:C;"<>red";C:C;"blue";C:C;"gold") but display "0" :/. I was expecting 2 (rows 2 and 7)

Comment: I found the following formula but is there a cleanier way to do it ? In the case we have like 5 criteria, using 5 operators "+" will be a mess? nope ?
=NB.SI.ENS(B:B;"GER";C:C;"blue")+NB.SI.ENS(B:B;"GER";C:C;"gold")

Comment: @Icy In this case, you do not need to state the <>gold - if it is red or blue, it cannot be gold (since you just have one color column. Your formula would be close to what you already had in the beginning: `=SUM(COUNTIFS(B2:B10;"GER";C2:C10;{"blue";"red"}))`